# How to aggregate iOS push notifications using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

so I'm developing an application where a user might get a notification based on some action but I only want the user to receive one notification of a specific type. An example might illustrate this better:

Say a user on facebook makes a facebook post. If someone likes the post they'll get a notification. However, if 20 different people like that post I don't want 20 separate notifications when they finally check their phone. I want one notification that says '20 people have liked your post.' I also only want to track the new notifications. Say 20 people have liked your post. I don't want the notification for the next 5 who've liked your post to be '25 people have liked your post.' I want it to be '5 new people have liked your post.'

What I don't know how to do is delete a notification that got sent using Parse. An idea I thought of off the top of my head for recording new posts was to keep track of what the user has seen for that post but that seems silly. It's a large amount of data to keep track of, compared to querying for a previous notification to that user for that channel (is that possible?).

Anyways, I was hoping other users of Parse using push notifications might've faced this problem and how you all might've gotten around it. I would like to implement my own backend but I don't have the expertise and I'm currently focused on the client side. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you have don't have the control to cancel a **Push Notification**. However, you do have a control when to send even how to send it. If you want to implement something like you say, you have to do custom works on that. You might observe a period of time like 2-3 minutes whether there are more than for example 10 notifications you want to send. If so, send one instead.

Before iOS 8, Push Notification did have so many limitations like we can not have our own custom action. But now, I think Apple will let us do more as time goes by.

Comment: yup. I've been looking into it all day and I haven't found anything. Thank you for your reply and suggestion.

Comment: Ya, I put this issue aside and when I read your comment about how you control the ability to send notifications, it gave me a new idea.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way but here's how I plan on implementing the feature. I'm going to add a notifications array to the user ([Notification objects]), this will also allow me to query for notifications for a possible notifications page. Say this were facebook and the user gets a new like notification on a post (1 like total).

I will create a new notification object and add it to the User object's notifications array with properties 'seen' set to false, 'prevNotificationLikes' set to 1, and then send out a notification. The message will be generic for singular/plural #'s of likes.

If someone else likes the post before the user responded to the push notification, I will see that the user hasn't 'seen' (false) the first notification and I will not send out a new notification.

Say 19 people like the post and then the user checks the initial notification and sets the 'seen' property to true. The next notification check on the cloud code for the 21st like will query to see if there are any previous notifications for that post/user. Parse cloud will then find a corresponding notification for that post/like where prevNotificationLikes is equal to 1 and update that number to 21. If the 'seen' property is set to true, then it'll send out a notification '20 new people have liked your post.' I know that the notifications are sent 1 step late with the fact that the user probably already knows that 19 people have liked the post but it'll be a compromise to get the job done.

Any critique is welcome. Sorry for wall of text instead of code. I'm just writing out my idea before writing the code so that I have something to follow along.

Comment: * '20 people have liked your post,' not '20 new people have liked your post'

Comment: will probably do total likes instead of new likes

Comment: Should be better to show codes cause no one wants to read this.